# Check docker alpine musl version

Tags: c, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux, musl

We have docker files which based on alpine linux.
I want for the built container to check the version of the `musl` library ,
I mean run the container and and in RT check the musl version
how can I do that ?

I've tried something like

```
docker run -it --rm alpine /bin/ash
```

**and run**

```
musl -v
```

**Got**

```
/bin/ash: musl: not found
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`libc` itself is an executable. You can run it and the usage message will print out the version:

```
/ # /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1
musl libc (x86_64)
Version 1.1.24
Dynamic Program Loader
Usage: /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 [options] [--] pathname [args]
```

Comment: another question :) I try the same on the ssl libary and I got `/ # lib/libssl.so.1.1 
Segmentation fault
` any idea how to overcome this ?